# How to protect aws cloudfront/s3 static files loading from cdn bucket to only specific domain websites

Tags: amazon-web-services, cdn

I have some static files inside cdn bucket and i want to restrict to load it from only specific domains for example -https://test.website.com,https://test.website1.com How to achieve in aws cdn/s3 settings

Comment: Which CDN? CloudFront? Also is the domain the CDN or are websites referencing the resources  to the CDN on their own websites?

Comment: yes aws cloud-front..website domains are another normal websites